# What are the subsets of the Eijiro corpus about?

Tags: corpora, japanese

I'm working with 2 japanese corpora called 'waei' and 'reiji'.
They are legacy data, so I have no README or else to tell me the topic of either of them. But I need to know what they are about.

My Japanese is limited.
From what i found on the internet, mainly [here](https://github.com/edvakf/EijiroX/blob/master/src/background/eijiro.js)

The eijiro corpus is a crowd-driven example database that can be divided into 4 subsets:

- eiji:  '英辞郎'
- ryaku: '略語郎'
- waei:  '和英辞郎'
- reiji: '例辞郎'

I assume:

- eiji is en->jp
- waei is jp->en
- ryaku is abbreviations
- reiji no Idea

Does anyone know more about this (and for sure)?